# "No Such File or Directory" in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an encryption program that is also capable of using a username and password to be accessed, alongside the password being able to be changed, however, I am getting the following error when trying to read the password from a file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/a.py", line 28, in <module>
    password()
  File "C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/a.py", line 9, in password
    var2 = open("Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\password.txt","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users\\Matthew\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\password.txt'
```

Password is saved in the `Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\password.txt directory`.

Below is the code.

```
import os
import time
def password():
    while True:
        username = input ("Enter Username: ")
        password = input ("Enter Password: ")

        var1 = "admin"
        var2 = open("Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\password.txt","r")
        if username == var1 and password == var2:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            answer = input("Do you wish to change your password (Y/N): ")
            if input == "Y" or "y":
                var2 = input("Enter new password: ")
            elif input == "N" or "n":
                break
            logged()
            break

        else:
            print ("Password did not match!")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to the encryption program.")

password()

def main():
    result = 'Your message is: '
    message = ''
    choice = 'none'

    while choice != '-1':
        choice = input("\nDo you want to encrypt or decrypt the message?\nEnter 1 to Encrypt, 2 to Decrypt, -1 to Exit Program: ")

        if choice == '1':
            message = input("\nEnter the message to encrypt: ")

            for i in range(0, len(message)):
                result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)

                print (result + '\n\n')
                result = ''

        elif choice == '2':
            message = input("\nEnter the message to decrypt: ")

            for i in range(0, len(message)):
                result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) + 2)

                print (result + '\n\n')
                result = ''

        elif choice != '-1':
            print ("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again.\n\n")

        elif choice == '-1':
            exit()

main()
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide the complete path:

```
var2 = open("C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/password.txt","r")
```

---

## Edit:

As you said in the comment that it worked but the password was marked as incorrect, so I have fixed issues with your code.
You cannot read data directly by opening a file. You will have to use the command `read` to get the data:

```
file = open("C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/password.txt","r")
var2 = file.read()
file.close()
```

---

Your second code problem is setting new password. The code you made:

```
answer = input("Do you wish to change your password (Y/N): ")
if input == "Y" or "y":
    var2 = input("Enter new password: ")
elif input == "N" or "n":
    break
```

Don't use `input` to see the value, use the variable in which you stored the input data. Also `lower` the string to make it easy:

```
answer = input("Do you wish to change your password (Y/N): ")
if answer.lower() == "y":
    var2 = input("Enter new password: ")
elif answer.lower() == "n":
    break
```

---

The full code can be like:

```
import os
import time
def password():
    while True:
        username = input ("Enter Username: ")
        password = input ("Enter Password: ")

        var1 = "admin"
        file = open("C:/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/password.txt","r")
        var2 = file.read()
        file.close()
        if username == var1 and password == var2:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            answer = input("Do you wish to change your password (Y/N): ")
            if answer.lower() == "y":
                var2 = input("Enter new password: ")
            elif answer.lower() == "n":
                break
            logged()
            break

        else:
            print ("Incorrect Information!")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to the Encryption program.")

password()

def main():
    result = 'Your message is: '
    message = ''
    choice = 'none'

    while choice != '-1':
        choice = input("\nDo you want to encrypt or decrypt the message?\nEnter 1 to Encrypt, 2 to Decrypt, -1 to Exit Program: ")

        if choice == '1':
            message = input("\nEnter the message to encrypt: ")

            for i in range(0, len(message)):
                result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)

                print (result + '\n\n')
                result = ''

        elif choice == '2':
            message = input("\nEnter the message to decrypt: ")

            for i in range(0, len(message)):
                result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) + 2)

                print (result + '\n\n')
                result = ''

        elif choice != '-1':
            print ("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again.\n\n")

        elif choice == '-1':
            exit()

main()
```

Comment: It works like that, but for some reason is stating that the password is incorrect, when it shouldn't be, as the password is "admins".